# String being passed in says there are two arguments

Tags: python, integer, arguments, parameter-passing, addition

bit of an issue with a function I'm writing for adding and subtracting a value located within a class.

I'm trying to pass a value that I've read in from a csv to my add function. This value is a decimal value (e.g. 500.00) I've tried eliminating the trailing 0's to make it just 500, this didn't work either. I keep getting:

```
TypeError: add() takes exactly one argument (two given).
```

Even though I have a print statement confirming its only trying to pass in the 500.

Here's my function:

```
def add(amount):
    self.total = self.total + amount
```

It's being called by `v.add(i)` Even if I set i to an arbitray integer value it still results in the same error. I am relatively inexperience with python, so perhaps there is something simple I'm missing here. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a `self` before the `amount` parameter. Also, try using `v().add(i)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, total=0.):
        self.total = total

    def add(self, amount):     # <= needs `self` parameter
        self.total += amount

v = Myclass()
v.add(2.)
```

When you call an object method, it implicitly passes a reference to the object - so calling `v.add(something)` actually calls `Myclass.add(v, something)`.

Voila - two parameters, when you told it to only expect one...

Comment: Spot on. Thanks, I knew it was something silly. I had missed putting that in on that function and kept overlooking it. I'll accept on the delay is up!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have 2 issues:

1. the normal definition of a method presumes the 'self' argument

   def add(self, amount):
2. you appear to be dealing with a string if you are trying to remove trailing zeros.
   you may wish/need to convert the string value "500.00" to a floating point value

   self.total = self.total + float(amount)

If you try to add a string to a number, Python will complain. You can see the type of an object being held in a variable using the type() function. E.g., you may wish to print the type of the 'amount' argument inside the add() method like this (for debugging):

```
print "the type of amount is", type(amount)
```

It will show you what you have (str, int, etc.)

(BTW it would probably be better style to convert it outside the method and have the method accept only numeric values for amount.)